# Flash virtual stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a loader, that loads an external flash application. This flash application uses a Stage reference to draw its contents to a stage. What I need is to make indent below the stage so that the downloaded application could not draw it. I thought of creating a virtual stage for my loaded app, but I do not know how to do this and can not find anything regarding this question. If you could tell me where to read about the problem or suggest another solution, I would be very grateful.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Apparently you cannot create a new stage, unless you're in AIR, there you can create a `NativeWindow` and put the loaded SWF in there. I say kick the loaded SWF's developer in the a$$ so he won't behave like a jerk, and write his app to use main class as the standpoint instead of stage.

Answer (score 0):

Ive foud a solution! Ive overrided addchild of stage so that when the loaded swf calls it it will add children to my Sprite that holds the whole loaded app.